# Swagger generator doesn't recognize controller

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have this yaml file:

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: 0.1.0
  title: "My API"
host: localhost:3000
basePath: /api
schemes:
  - http
paths:
    /weather:
      get:
        x-swagger-router-controller: "weatherController"
        description: "Returns current weather in the specified city to the caller"
        operationId: getWeather
        parameters:
          - name: city
            in: query
            description: "The city you want weather for in the form city,state,country"
            required: true
            type: "string"
```

When I run swagger-codegen-cli, generates /api/Default.js and /api/DefaultService.js , but no /api/weatherController.js.

I've tried also with this:

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: 0.1.0
  title: "My API"
host: localhost:3000
basePath: /api
schemes:
  - http
paths:
    /weather:
      x-swagger-router-controller: "weatherController"
      get:
        description: "Returns current weather in the specified city to the caller"
        operationId: getWeather
        parameters:
          - name: city
            in: query
            description: "The city you want weather for in the form city,state,country"
            required: true
            type: "string"
```

And I run the generator with this command:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -l nodejs-server -o output -i api.yaml
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's a bug, it would be great if you could file that on the swagger-codegen project.  But as a work around, consider adding a tag:

```
/weather:
  x-swagger-router-controller: "weatherController"
  get:
    tags:
    - weatherController
    description: "Returns current weather in the specified city to the caller"
    operationId: getWeather
    parameters:
      - name: city
        in: query
        description: "The city you want weather for in the form city,state,country"
        required: true
        type: "string"
```

Comment: That's a crappy solution even if it's working... I added an issue on swagger-codegen to track this issue: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4156