# Cannot resolve configured swagger-router handler

Tags: node.js, swagger-2.0, apigee

When I submit a POST request from my Vuejs app to my a127/apigee-127 Rest Service the http response is a 500:

```
{"message":"Cannot resolve the configured swagger-router handler: IAGController_post"}
```

What seems to be happening is the a127 Rest WebService is adding "_post" to the name of my IAGController and I cant figure out why?

Vuejs code:

```
let path = 'http://localhost:10010/iag';       
this.$http.post(path, {body: {grantType: 'bar', apiKey: 'abc', apiSecret: 'defg'}, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
          .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

RESTFul WebService Code:

Swagger:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: Hello World App
host: localhost:10010
basePath: /
schemes:
 - http
 - https
produces:
  - application/json
x-a127-config: {}
x-a127-services: {}
paths:
  /iag:
    x-swagger-router-controller: IAGController
    x-a127-apply: {}
    post:
      consumes: [application/json]
      parameters:  
        - name: body
          in: body
          description: Request a secure token
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/IAGSecurityRequest"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            # a pointer to a definition
            $ref: "#/definitions/tokenResponse"
        # responses may fall through to errors
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
definitions:
  IAGSecurityRequest:
    type: object
    properties:
      grantType:
        type: string
      apiKey:
        type: string
      apiSecret:
        type: string
ErrorResponse:
    type: string
  tokenResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      access_token:
        type: string
      token_type:
        type: string
      expires_in:
        type: integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this: 
[Swagger generator doesn't recognize controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295951/swagger-generator-doesnt-recognize-controller)

Any maybe you have also to start your function name with `get....`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens because in the swagger file the x-swagger-router-controller value doesn't correspond to the controller file name or the controller filename has been changed.

Also declaring async function in your controller may cause the issue

```
module.exports.postCall =  function postCall(req, res, next) {
```